# Share a reference variable in two collections

Tags: rust

I am trying to share a reference in two collections: a map and a list. I want to push to both of the collections and remove from the back of the list and remove from the map too. This code is just a sample to present what I want to do, it doesn't even compile!

What is the right paradigm to implement this? What kind of guarantees are the best practice?

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, LinkedList};

struct Data {
    url: String,
    access: u64,
}

struct Holder {
    list: LinkedList<Box<Data>>,
    map: HashMap<String, Box<Data>>,
}

impl Holder {
    fn push(&mut self, d: Data) {
        let boxed = Box::new(d);
        self.list.push_back(boxed);
        self.map.insert(d.url.to_owned(), boxed);
    }

    fn remove_last(&mut self) {
        if let Some(v) = self.list.back() {
            self.map.remove(&v.url);
        }
        self.list.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea of storing a single item in multiple collections simultaneously is not new... and is not simple.

The common idea to sharing elements is either doing it unsafely (knowing how many collections there are) or doing it with a shared pointer.

There is a some inefficiency in just blindly using regular collections with a shared pointer:

- Node based collections mean you have a double indirection
- Switching from one view to the other require finding the element all over again

In Boost.MultiIndex (C++), the paradigm used is to create an intrusive node to wrap the value, and then link this node in the various views. The trick (and difficulty) is to craft the intrusive node in a way that allows getting to the surrounding elements to be able to "unlink" it in O(1) or O(log N).

It would be quite `unsafe` to do so, and I don't recommend attempting it unless you are ready to spend significant time on it.

Thus, for a quick solution:

```
type Node = Rc<RefCell<Data>>;

struct Holder {
    list: LinkedList<Node>,
    map: HashMap<String, Node>,
}
```

As long as you do not need to remove by `url`, this is efficient enough.

---

Complete example:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, LinkedList};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Data {
    url: String,
    access: u64,
}

type Node = Rc<RefCell<Data>>;

struct Holder {
    list: LinkedList<Node>,
    map: HashMap<String, Node>,
}

impl Holder {
    fn push(&mut self, d: Data) {
        let url = d.url.to_owned();
        let node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(d));
        self.list.push_back(Rc::clone(&node));
        self.map.insert(url, node);
    }

    fn remove_last(&mut self) {
        if let Some(node) = self.list.back() {
            self.map.remove(&node.borrow().url);
        }
        self.list.pop_back();
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: What about performance issues in `RefCell` as I know it has `RWLock` for items. Isn't that bad in huge amount data?

Comment: @NavidNabavi It's semantically like a RWLock in that it allows many readers but only one writer. But unlike locks, it doesn't need to work across threads, so acquiring a mutable reference is literally an ordinary non-atomic memory access (close to the very data you'll later access so it's practically free) and a conditional jump. This is dirt cheap, the only potential slowdown is because it takes an additional word of memory, which may hurt the cache. But why don't you benchmark it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) instead of `Box`.

Alternatively, you could store indexes into your list as the value type of your hash map (i.e. use `HashMap<String, usize>` instead of `HashMap<String, Box<Data>>`.

Depending on what you are trying to do, it might be a better idea to only have either a list or a map, and not both.

Comment: I need to access by string to values, and remove by list. this is why I must use both for better performance. And I may mutablity is another key is needed.

Comment: Using only a map rather than both a map and a list would actually have better performance than what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I will lost the sequence of my data by insertion.

Comment: If you need mutability, you can use a `RefCell` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I know about RefCell but is not efficient. I think I have to do it unsafely.

Comment: Note that if you need performance, a linked list is rarely the way to go, especially since you only `{pop,push}_back`. You could store a `HashMap<String, *const Data>>` and use some `unsafe` blocks. As long as you ensure that the list and the map are synced this will be a safe wrapper for you particular data structure.

Comment: I need a priority queue which is element will removed from any where, this is why i need a Linkedlist. so because I gonna remove from anywhere of my sequential collection, link list will perform better in my use case, by the way my question is to have shared references in to collection and the sample is not giving of the details of the things I will need in the future. But surly I need these work together.

Comment: @NavidNabavi: Don't be sure about linked-list performing better for removals in the middle; the performance benefits only kick in for *large* lists, so you would have to measure the performance compared to a `Vec` (and especially, if order does not matter, `Vec::swap_remove` which is O(1) too).

Comment: Gonna remove from the middle and add to the front in every access and it is growing.

Comment: The size gonna grow to 1M data. I can handle this in Go, C++ or things like nodejs or python. but I preferred rust to some learning reasons.